# Cypress redirect e2e test with stripe js

Tags: api-testing, e2e, cypress

I am writing an e2e test in cypress for an online store and after clicking the confirm purchase button it redirects to stripe page (not iframe but one-time payment redirect to their website) to input credit card and then redirects back to our store to show the receipt.

Does anyone know what should be the best way to perform this test? Should it be API? How to use stripe API to do the payment using cy.request in order to avoid redirecting to their page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as per [official cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites), you should avoid using `cy.visit()` when testing an external site. They also list a bunch of reasons why this is not the best approach:

> However, you should never use your UI or visit a 3rd party site when testing because:
>
> - It is incredibly time consuming and slows down your tests.
> - The 3rd party site may have changed or updated its content.
> - The 3rd party site may be having issues outside of your control.
> - The 3rd party site may detect you are testing via a script and block you.
> - The 3rd party site may be running A/B campaigns.
>
> (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites)

So, in your case, you're better off with `cy.request()`. For that, you need:

- read their [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites), if you don't know how to use `cy.request()`
- read a documentation of yout API; I'm not sure what payment provider you're using, so I can link more resources for you to have a look at

Comment: There is another complication, we have our own receipt and invoice generated after the transaction is made, so if we stub the response, we cannot check our invoice

Comment: We do not visit, when you click on the button it goes to a redirect (it's not the old stripe popup) but the new stripe checkout is not API, but it's a redirect https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments

Comment: I don't really know this Stripe, it might complicate things if there is no API as I understand from your comment. I mean it's not that you can go to an external page in Cypress, it's just not recommended.

Comment: @DanielVianna I have the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @bigsee
Yes. The solution is: don't test a third party.

Comment: @bigsee
Not ideal solution, What I have done was doing separate tests. We mock the response by creating a different UI button (changed back-end to support this), so we have one button that does real transaction and another for test mock. Then I have a second test in cypress which is a pure API call to Stripe checking API key and a 200 response, It's like a health monitor.

Comment: @DanielVianna very helpful, thanks! sounds less than ideal as you say, but better than nothing I guess!